# Fatal error with the tagadelic module

Tags: 7

I have this error after the installation of the tagadelic 7.x-2.x-dev module:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function tagadelic_get_weighted_tags() in /home/www/2374fcf941c82d5986ed6d27587b81e0/web/sites/all/modules/cumulus/cumulus.module on line 120

How can I recover my site?

Comment: Also note that in general installing a -dev module is a really bad idea. For reasons like here: an incompatibility between a rewritten module and one depending on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to your database panel (for example PHPMyAdmin) and run following query:

```
UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='tagadelic';
```

Additionally, if you are using Drupal 7, run:

```
DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list';
```

After then you can uninstall problematic module via administration panel.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem with tagadelic module, and cumulus module, and i use drupal 7.x. I copyed the code from http://www.startel.kz/sites/all/modules/tagadelic/tagadelic.module , for the tagadelic file, did wonders works great.